# Stop some messages from syntastic

Tags: plugin-syntastic

I am coding in LaTeX, and syntastic seems to come up with messages that don't actually flag up errors. One in particular is `possible unwanted space at "{"` in this piece of code on lines 1 and 2.

```
\tikzset{
box/.style={
    regular polygon,
    regular polygon sides=6,
    minimum size=1cm,
    inner sep=0mm,
    outer sep=0mm,
    rotate=90,
    draw
}
}
```

Is there any way I can supress certain syntastic messages such as this one?

Comment: Read syntastic help, see what backends are enabled for LaTeX, disable or configure the culprit. Syntastic only comes up with the results of the  backends it runs, you still have to read about & configure those.

Comment: Syntastic checkers for TeX / LaTeX are mostly useless.  There is little point in keeping them enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, syntastic can filter out certain messages. Read `:help 'syntastic_quiet_messages'` for details.

All you have to do is fill this dictionary in your vimrc with a regex like this:

```
let g:syntastic_quiet_messages = { "regex": [
        \ '\mpossible unwanted space at "{"',
        \ 'SOME OTHER SYNTASTIC MESSAGE',
        ...
        \ ] }
```